# Full cycle FFT (getting the fundamental frequency magnitude)

Tags: signal-processing, fft

I´m trying to do a full cycle FFT (Sampling time=15360),

my approach is:

1) fft a signal with 256 samples (starting in some position).

2) abs it, get the magnitude of the fundamental frequency (previously knowed).

Am I right ?

Andre

Comment: What do you mean by "full cycle" FFT ? What is it that you are actually trying to achieve ?

Comment: Hi Paul, I´m trying to write a code, similar to http://www.mathworks.com/help/physmod/sps/powersys/ref/fourier.html.

Comment: OK, but what are you actually trying to *achieve* ? What's the end result that you need for your application ?

Comment: Paul, at the end, what I want is the Fourier MAGNITUDE (windowed by 256 samples) of a signal at its fundamental frequency.

Comment: OK, it still doesn't make much sense - if you take a step back from the *details* and just describe what the *application* is (e.g, guitar tuner, spectrogram plotter, pitch tracker, etc) then it will be easier to tell you how to apply the FFT.

Comment: Does 256 samples cover exactly 1 period of the fundamental frequency of the signal?

Comment: Hotpaw, frequency in 60Hz, sampled at 15360Hz. Thanks.